# Ссылка растягивается на целую ширину блока

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox

Тема такая, что я задал блоку **display: flex;** При этом, в нем находится ссылка, которая растягивается на целую ширину блока (хотя я ей задал **display: block**). Как сделать кликабельный только текст, а не и области по бокам(т.е. красная зона должна быть некликабельной)?
Заранее спасибо.

```css
.join{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.join-btn{
  display: block;
  background-color: red; /*для проверки наличия областей ссылки*/
}
```

```html
  <div class="join">
    <h1>Join Fighter Community Today!</h1>
    <a href="#" class="join-btn">Join Us</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.join{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.join-btn{
  display: block;
  background-color: red; /*для проверки наличия областей ссылки*/
}
```

```html
<div class="join">
  <h1>Join Fighter Community Today!</h1>
  <a href="#" class="join-btn">Join Us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А можете пояснить пожалуйста, как align-items решил этот вопройс?

Answer (score -1):

Нужно заменить на : align-self: flex-start;

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]